# Snipe Command not shwoing last deleted message

Tags: discord.js

So I added a snip command in my bot. While testing it I send a message then delete it. I do ;snipe and it returns with @CasuallyNick, there are no recently deleted messages! When I know the message was deleted.

Here is the code

```
const { MessageEmbed } = require('discord.js');
module.exports ={
  config:{
    name: "snipe",
    category: "info",
    description: "Shows the most recent deleted message.",
    usage: ";snipe"
  },
    run: async(client, message, args) => {
        const msg = client.snipes.get(message.channel.id);
        if(!msg) return message.reply("There are no recently deleted messages!");

        const embed = new MessageEmbed()
            .setAuthor(`Deleted by ${msg.author.tag}`, msg.author.displayAvatarURL())
            .setDescription(msg.content);
      message.channel.send(embed)
    }
}
```

I don't know if it has to do with discords new update or if I am missing something!

Comment: `Client.snipes` doesn't seem to exist in Discord.js, what are you referring to? ([`Client`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client) docs)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, what is `client.snipes` ? I'm guessing its a `Discord.Collection` you made, everything else looks fine so it must be how you set values of `client.snipes`

On your message handler do you have this or something similar?

```js
client.on("message", msg => {
    client.snipes.set(msg.channel.id, msg);
});
```